# Using MariaDB JDBC client to perform IAM authentification with AWS RDS Proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, micronaut, amazon-rds-proxy

I have a very hard time configuring RDS Proxy w/ IAM authentification.

On the RDS Proxy:

- TLS is enable
- IAM authentification is enable as well

A secret containing native MySQL credentials is created and use by the RDS Proxy, on the monitoring I saw some connections... It is OK.

But, on my application (Micronaut one), I use the MariaDB JDCB with paramaters:

On the instance, I already import certificates with a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Downloading RDS certificates..."
curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem > rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem
csplit -sk rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem "/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/" "{$(grep -c 'BEGIN CERTIFICATE' rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem | awk '{print $1 - 2}')}"
for CERT in xx*; do
# extract a human-readable alias from the cert
ALIAS=$(openssl x509 -noout -text -in $CERT | perl -ne 'next unless /Subject:/; s/.*CN=//; print')
echo "importing $ALIAS"
# import the cert into the default java keystore
keytool -import -cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias "$ALIAS" -file $CERT
done
```

and my application contains dependencies:

```
implementation "org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:2.7.4"
implementation "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-rds:1.12.74"
```

and datasources:

```
datasources:
  default:
    url: jdbc:mariadb://XXXXXX/DATABASE?user=INSTANCE_PROFILE_NAME&credentialType=AWS-IAM&&verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true&Unicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
    driverClassName: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    type: org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPoolDataSource
```

Instance profile role contains a policy with:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "rds-db:connect",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:rds-db:eu-west-1:794392443626:dbuser:prx-XXXXXXXXX/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

But ! It doesn't work at all !

```
Sep 28 09:53:55 ip-192-168-11-29 web: Caused by: java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: (conn=71837971) Access denied for user 'INSTANCE_PROFILE_NAME'@'%' (using password: YES)
Sep 28 09:53:55 ip-192-168-11-29 web: Current charset is UTF-8. If password has been set using other charset, consider using option 'passwordCharacterEncoding'
Sep 28 09:53:55 ip-192-168-11-29 web: at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:66) ~[ads-2021.09.28.100752-all.jar:?]
Sep 28 09:53:55 ip-192-168-11-29 web: at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.create(ExceptionFactory.java:192) ~[ads-2021.09.28.100752-all.jar:?]
Sep 28 09:53:55 ip-192-168-11-29 web: at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.authenticationHandler(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:769) ~[ads-2021.09.28.100752-all.jar:?]
Sep 28 09:53:55 ip-192-168-11-29 web: at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.createConnection(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:555) ~[ads-2021.09.28.100752-all.jar:?]
Sep 28 09:53:55 ip-192-168-11-29 web: at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1389) ~[ads-2021.09.28.100752-all.jar:?]
Sep 28 09:53:55 ip-192-168-11-29 web: at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:635) ~[ads-2021.09.28.100752-all.jar:?]
Sep 28 09:53:55 ip-192-168-11-29 web: at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.newConnection(MariaDbConnection.java:150) ~[ads-2021.09.28.100752-all.jar:?]
Sep 28 09:53:55 ip-192-168-11-29 web: at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:89) ~[ads-2021.09.28.100752-all.jar:?]
```

on the cloudwatch rds proxy side, I have:

```
2021-09-28T10:24:58.140Z [DEBUG] [proxyEndpoint=default] [clientConnection=3815433305] Received Handshake Response: [username="INSTANCE_PROFILE_NAME", schema="ads_beta", auth-plugin="mysql_native_password", capabilityFlags={CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS=true; CLIENT_LONG_FLAG=false; CLIENT_CONNECT_WITH_DB=true; CLIENT_COMPRESS=false; CLIENT_LOCAL_FILES=true; CLIENT_IGNORE_SPACE=true; CLIENT_INTERACTIVE=false; CLIENT_IGNORE_SIGPIPE=false; CLIENT_TRANSACTIONS=true; CLIENT_RESERVED=false; CLIENT_SECURE_CONNECTION=true; CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS=false; CLIENT_MULTI_RESULTS=true; CLIENT_PS_MULTI_RESULTS=true; CLIENT_PLUGIN_AUTH=true; CLIENT_CONNECT_ATTRS=true; CLIENT_PLUGIN_AUTH_LENENC_CLIENT_DATA=true; CLIENT_CAN_HANDLE_EXPIRED_PASSWORDS=false; CLIENT_SESSION_TRACK=true; CLIENT_DEPRECATE_EOF=true; CLIENT_OPTIONAL_RESULTSET_METADATA=false; CLIENT_REMEMBER_OPTIONS=false}]

Proxy authentication with MySQL native password authentication failed for user "INSTANCE_PROFILE_NAME" with TLS on. Reason: Invalid credentials. If you provide an IAM token, make sure to either use the correct password or enable IAM authentication
```

Maybe It miss some datasource configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_KEY and AWS_REGION defined as environment variables on your server? That was my problem. It seems the mariadb plugin requires those, cannot use the role-based configuration.

Here is a good blog on how to set up the role based authentication that will automatically refresh your db connection every 14 minutes (since the aws rds auth token is only valid for 15): https://blog.jdriven.com/2021/06/configure-hikari-connection-pool-when-using-rds-iam/